# Noetic released but still not working on Buster

Tags: rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I was noticed that Noetic was at last released for Debian buster the last 23th of May, but when I try to install it the same error occurs:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

Does anyone know something? It can be about the change of name from Raspbian Buster to Raspberry Pi OS?

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353836/noetic-released-but-still-not-working-on-buster/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would appear to be (almost) a duplicate of #q353123 (and #q353145).

Buster only gets `amd64` and `arm64` packages.

I haven't checked, but it's more than likely that Raspbian is still not 64 bit, so there aren't any binaries available for your platform.

---

Edit: just noticed: #q350055 is your own question, and in my edit there I also mentioned the fact that only `arm64` and `amd64` get binary packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-03**:
So the only solution is try to install an image of Debian of 64 bits, right?